# Determine the image of the map

Tags: analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by \begin{equation*}f: \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}u \\ v\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x(1-y) \\ xy\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

I want to determine th eimage $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

$$$$

We have that 
\begin{equation*}f\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \ \text{ und } \ f\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

Does this mean that $\text{im}(f)=\left \{\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\right \}$ ? Or do we have to do something else in this case where we don't have a linear map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can notice that the map is invertible in certain conditions.

If $(u,v)\in\mathbb R^2$ then $f(x=u+v,y=\dfrac v{u+v})=(u,v)$ except for $v=-u$.

Indeed these points cannot be reached since $x(1-y)=-xy\implies x=0$

And when $x=0$ then the whole axis is transformed to origin point : $f(0,y)=(0,0)$.

So the image $f(\mathbb R^2)$ is whole $\mathbb R^2$ except for the line $v=-u$ but still including origin.

Comment: By the line $v=-u$ that is not in the image you mean $x(1-y)=-xy$ or not?

Comment: $(x,y)$ are variables used for the initial space and $(u,v)$ for the image space. The line $v=-u$ cannot be in the image of $f$ because $x(1-x)=-xy$ is not possible. There are no $(x,y)$ that gives $f(x,y)=(u,-u)$ except for $(0,0)$.

Comment: Ah ok! What exactly do you mean that the map is invertible **in certain conditions** ?

Comment: Also what exactly is meany by **the whole axis is transformed to the origin** ?

Comment: it is invertible when $u+v\neq 0$, this is the condition. I meant axis $(Oy)$ that is points of the form $(0,y)$, they all go to $(0,0)$ when applying $f$, not to $(u,-v)$

Comment: I see!! Thank you very much!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is not linear. Hence, you can't assume that the image of $f$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$.

**Hint:** Consider
$$
f(x,y)=x\begin{pmatrix}1-y\\y\end{pmatrix}.
$$
You see that the image of $f$ contains all lines through $\begin{pmatrix}1-y\\y\end{pmatrix}$ for some $y\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Is this like that because $x$ is multiplied by that vector, or why?

Comment: All lines through the origin and that point, that is.

Comment: So, do we have in this case the parameter $x$ which is also the variable of the function? @aschepler